# Show network traffic over time in Unix

Tags: networking, unix

Some VPSes charge for outgoing network traffic per month, so how can I check on the Unix command line how much outgoing network traffic has run so far this month?

An ASCII graph where X is days and Y is traffic would be nice bonus :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to log it before you can display it. A popular logging and graphing tool is [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/).

(Posted this as a comment at first, but I guess it is a full answer in some respect.)